# Nest js read events from rabbitmq in websockets microservice

Tags: websocket, nestjs

I have created a microservice(notify-microservice) with rabbitmq connection. I have a product microservice from there i will be pushing an event to rabbitmq to notify the client about new product. In notify-microservice micro service i have a websocket in it. How can i read the events from rabbitmq to notify the clients.
Right now i am only able to read the events from rabbitmq from controller of microservice. How can i read from websocket file.

microservice main.ts file:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';


const logger = new Logger('Main');
const microserviceOptions = {
  transport: Transport.RMQ,
  options: {
    urls: ['amqp://<user_name>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<vhost>'],
    queue: '<queue_name>',
    queueOptions: {
      durable: false
    },
  }
}

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, microserviceOptions);
  app.listen(() => {
    logger.log("Socket micro service is listening...");
  })
}
bootstrap();
```

app.gateway.ts file

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, OnGatewayInit, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WsResponse } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Socket,Server } from 'socket.io';

import { EventPattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@WebSocketGateway(3001)

export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect{
    private Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');

    afterInit(server: Server) {
        this.Logger.log("App Gateway Initialized");
    }

    handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]){
        this.Logger.log(`New client connected...: ${client.id}`);
        client.emit('connected', 'Successfully connected to the server.');
    }

    handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
        this.Logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
    }


    @EventPattern('notify_new_product')
    notifyNewProduct(client:Socket, text:string):WsResponse<string> {
        this.Logger.log(`got new event`);
        return {event: 'notify_new_product', 'data': text};
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppGateway } from './app.gateway';
import { NotifyController } from './notify.controller';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [NotifyController],
  providers: [AppGateway],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

notify.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Logger, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventPattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class NotifyController {

  private logger = new Logger('NotifyController');

  @EventPattern('notify_new_product')
  async notify_new_product(product_id: string) {
    
    this.logger.log('Received new event to notify');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message Pattern Decorator should be used only within the controller classes since they are the entry points for your application.Using them inside providers won't have any effect as they are simply ignored by Nest.